# What is the result of a comparison between an integer and an object?

Tags: javascript, operators

What is JavaScript's behavior when comparing objects with integers?
For example:

```
var result = { test: 'blah' };
if (result < 0) {
    // when is this portion processed?
}
```

I am currently working with a `result` variable that could be either an integer (error code) or an object holding further details.

I guess I could use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` but I'm quite interested in knowing the shortest possible way to handle these situations...

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hello Josan. Yes, but I'm wondering in there are any differences between JS engines and if a general rule has been defined...

Comment: An alternative strategy is to have `result` always be an object with an error code (that is eg. 0 when no error has occurred) and a value. This way you don't give the value of `result` itself two responsibilities.

Comment: @groslouis Looking at the ECMAScript 2015 specification (specifically sections 12.9,3, 7.2.11, 7.1.1, 19.1.3.6, and 7.1.3.1), it would appear that the correct result of `{ 'test': 'blah' } < 0` should always be `false` in conforming implementations. The same should apply for any object with the standard `toString` and `valueOf` functions in the Object prototype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = {test: 'blah'};

if(result) {
   if (typeof result === 'object') {
     // do something
   } else if (typeof result === 'number') {
     // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes. So far it seems the safest way to handle that. Just trying to figure out the underlying logic of comparison statements.

Comment: All things in JS have types, that's how the comparison works.

Comment: I'm just fond of elegant notations... which imply mastering the language logic. But maybe there is no other way in JS... I'll let you know when I find out !

Comment: Indeed you are right. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854216/9109298.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering [...] if a general rule has been defined

Yes. The rules are described in [JavaScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). For your example:

```
{ test: "blah" } < 0
```

I have highlighted the sections and rules involved:

> 11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm
>   [...]
>   1.a Let px be the result of calling ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).

The expression `{ test: "blah" }` ends up as `"[object Object]"`

> 3.a Let nx be the result of calling ToNumber(px).

The expression `"[object Object]"` ends up as `NaN`

> 3.c If nx is NaN, return undefined.

The result of algorithm is `undefined`.

> 11.8.1 The Less-than Operator ( < )
>   [...]
>   6. If r is undefined, return false. Otherwise, return r.

The end result is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript will call the valueOf() method on the object automatically if you are comparing it to an integer. Similarly, when comparing to a string, the toString() method is used.

If you are not the creator of the object, there may or may not be a valueOf function, so the behavior of using a comparison operator can be unexpected if you haven't created the objects or done some additional testing logic and are just comparing objects and integers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

The following snippet shows some comparisons in action.

```js
var five = { 
  value: 5, 
  valueOf: function() { 
    return this.value 
  } 
};

var billion = { 
  value: 1000000000
};

console.log ( five.valueOf() );
console.log ( billion.valueOf() );
console.log ( billion > five );
console.log ( NaN > five );
console.log ( 6 > five );
console.log ( 4 > five );
```

Comment: All behaviors are predictable. If `valueOf` does not exist, `toString` is used. Then the rules of string-string or string-number comparisions are used. Have not tested but `billion > five` should be same as NaN > 5.

Comment: @SalmanA is right about all behaviors being predictable. When I added this answer there was another answer saying that the comparison of objects and integers is always false which is not the case. There are others here now that are simply responding to the one example case saying the same thing, making it seem like object/integer comparisons are always false but they are not. My use of the word unpredictable was in response to those types of answers so I have edited my answer to try and be helpful to future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Document on [**developer.mozilla.org**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) says that JS comparison logic when operand A is an Object and operand B is a Number, is defined this way:

```
ToPrimitive(A) == B
```

where

> ToPrimitive(A) attempts to convert its object argument to a primitive
>   value, by attempting to invoke varying sequences of A.toString and
>   A.valueOf methods on A.

Additionally, [**Mozilla JavaScript Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) states :

> If the method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns
>   "[object type]".

and

> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns [object
>   Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in the 5th
>   Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata.

So it is reasonable to say that in case of comparison with a Number, an Object will always be converted to a String.

Which is then handled this way:

```
ToNumber(A) === B
```

> ToNumber(A) attempts to convert its argument to a number before
>   comparison.  Its behavior is equivalent to +A (the unary + operator).

Finally, [Unary Plus doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) states that:

> If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Same doc on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) present a summary table showing that comparing a Number with NaN does always return false.

**So, unless in scenarios raised by [@JasonB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853875/9109298), the given code should work.**

**However, to avoid any error due to data-structure, the answer given by [@
John Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853895/9109298) is to be preferred**.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if result is an integer with `result.isInteger()` first and then perform whatever is needed if it is or treat it as an object otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you test the type of the `result` variable to determine if its a number or an object.

Test for an Object:

`typeof result === 'object'`

Test for a Number:

`Number.isInteger(result)`